# In Azure, how do you configure pull requests so that some tasks must run successfully before a PR can be merged?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pull-request

In my Azure build pipeline, we have tasks for running tests and code coverage ...

[image]

However, we would like to require that tests are run prior to merging our pull requests into the branch from which the above pipeline draws its source.  However, I can't figure out what setting in Azure will allow us to customize what tasks are run prior to a pull request being able to be approved.

The question is -- how do we customize a pull request so that it can only be approved if tests are run and pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by configuring the **Build Validation** for the target branch.

> Validate code by pre-merging and building pull request changes.

Check below steps:

Go the **Branches** under **Repos** in azure project portal-->Select the target **Branch** the PR merged into-->Click the **3dots** and choose **Branch polices**

[image]

On the Branch policy setting page-->Click the plus **+**  to add build validation pipline-->Select your build pipeline as the validation pipeline.

[image]

After the Build Validation is configured for the target Branch. The validation pipeline must succeed before the PR can be merged.

See [Branch policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops) for more information about protecting your important branches and enforcing your team's code quality.

Comment: what does pre-merging mean? Is it like a throw-away merging? at the end one wants to know if the PR works with *target* code..

Answer (score 0):

You may try the standard mechanism of azure devops git - branch policy. Assign your build to your target branch and set it as a required check. Then you can not merge if the build failed. Check this documentation: [Build validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#build-validation).